# "standard" type in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I created the index in ElasticSearch with the following structure

```
{
    "my_index2": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "age": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "my_index2",
                "creation_date": "1573022346897",
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "my_analyzer": {
                            "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                        }
                    },
                    "tokenizer": {
                        "my_tokenizer": {
                            "token_chars": [
                                "letter",
                                "digit",
                                "whitespace",
                                "punctuation",
                                "symbol"
                            ],
                            "type": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "S6fjaa12QiqTFHrqjBE3KQ",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7040299"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my data:

```
{
  "took": 17,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 9,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "ou57P24BbiLEFIdnhkkg",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Hung Le",
          "age": "34"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "o-57P24BbiLEFIdnx0kj",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Viet Pham",
          "age": "20"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "pO58P24BbiLEFIdnAUm-",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Quy Tran",
          "age": "21"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "pe58P24BbiLEFIdnJ0mn",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Khiem Pham",
          "age": "22"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "pu58P24BbiLEFIdngUnX",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "PhamHoangViet",
          "age": "21"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "p-59P24BbiLEFIdnPUma",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Nguyễn Trần Trung Quân",
          "age": "21"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "qO59P24BbiLEFIdnbkkO",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Đặng Tấn Sĩ",
          "age": "21"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "qe5_P24BbiLEFIdnDknH",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Văn Trung",
          "age": "34"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "qu5_P24BbiLEFIdnZkm3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Phạm Nguyễn Minh Quân",
          "age": "34"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I searched with the keyword "Trung Quân":

```
http://localhost:9200/my_index2/_search?q=name:Trung+Quân
```

And here are the results:

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 2.19989,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "p-59P24BbiLEFIdnPUma",
        "_score": 2.19989,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Nguyễn Trần Trung Quân",
          "age": "21"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "qe5_P24BbiLEFIdnDknH",
        "_score": 1.497693,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Văn Trung",
          "age": "34"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "qu5_P24BbiLEFIdnZkm3",
        "_score": 1.099945,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Phạm Nguyễn Minh Quân",
          "age": "34"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It retrieves all results that contain the word "Trung" or the word "Quân". Now How I have to configure the index so that the result contains both "Trung" and "Quân" as the following:

```
{
  "took": 9,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 2.6052008,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "p-59P24BbiLEFIdnPUma",
        "_score": 2.6052008,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Nguyễn Trần Trung Quân",
          "age": "21"
        }
      }

    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tired terms query, term query enables one to search using multiple values for a specified something like name:{"Trung","Quân"}. here is the reference https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `name` is mapped as a multi-field, which means it gets stored twice in Elasticsearch:

- once optimized for full-text search (referenced as `name`), and
- once optimized for analytics and exact match (referenced as `name.keyword`)

If all you are interested in is exact match search and **not** full-text search, you can achieve that by "fixing" your mapping. Just map `name` as a field of type `keyword` and re-index your documents. Mapping for field `name`:

```
"name": {
    "type": "keyword"
}
```

If you want to keep full-text search capability (when querying against the `name`-field) you should leave your mapping as is, and try one of the following queries:

**#1 Example using phrase search:**
(no exact match needed, but both terms need to match in the proper sequence/order. by using double quotes)

```
http://localhost:9200/my_index2/_search?q=name:"Trung Quân"
```

**#2 Example using exact match:**
(whole name needs to match from beginning to end, with exact same casing and accents)

```
http://localhost:9200/my_index2/_search?q=name.keyword:"Trung Quân"
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved this problem by adding "" like this: "Trung Quân"